# Using go-pg to retrieve virtual columns from Postgres

Tags: database, postgresql, go, orm, go-pg

I'm using `go-pg` (https://github.com/go-pg/pg) and this code:

```golang
type Book struct {
  id   int
  name string
}

var books []Book
err := db.Model(&books).Select()
```

and everything works good but I need to add a "virtual" column like this:

```sql
concat ('info:', 'id:', id, '...') AS info
```

and I tried to use:

```golang
query.ColumnExpr("concat ('info:', 'id:', id, '...') AS info")
```

but:

1. go-pg complains with: `error="pg: can't find column=info in model=Book (try discard_unknown_columns)"`
2. go-pg doesn't include anymore columns `id` and `name` in query: `concat...` ONLY!

I can understand that because now go-pg doesn't know how to bind data, but I really need that string which I can retrieve from DB only.

**Is there a way?**

Can I use a custom type like this below?

```golang
type CustomBook struct {
  Info string
  Book
}
```

Does this make sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this approach could work for you:

```
type Book struct {
  ID   int
  Name string
  Info string `pg:"-"`
}

...
db.Model(&books).ColumnExpr("book.*").ColumnExpr("CONCAT('id:', id, 'name:', name) AS info").Select()
```

`pg:"-"` ignores the struct field and it is not created nor it produces any errors

this ignored column is documented here: https://pg.uptrace.dev/models/

another approach, depending on your requirements could be like this:

```
var r []struct {
  Name string
  Info string
}

db.Model((*Book)(nil)).Column("name").ColumnExpr("CONCAT('id:', id, 'name:', name) AS info").Select(&r)
```

this second one is documented here: https://pg.uptrace.dev/queries/